# Python regex findall unexpected output

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 to read a file and I wish to use regex on the contents of the file to extract certain information. However my current regex is including extra data that I don't seem to be able to get rid of.

```
for event in reader:
    #print(event)
    strevent = str(event)
    print re.findall(r"protocol':(.*?),", strevent)
```

The above code works and the output for the **re.findall** command is:

```
[' 6']
```

But im looking for the output to just be **6**

This is a snippet of the contents of the file I'm reading in

```
["{'protocol': 6", " 'dport-icode': 80", " 'signature-id': 15", " 'mpls-    label': None",
 " 'sensor-id': 0", " 'impact-flag': 0""]
```

The aim is to extract the data between the identification tags and stick them into variables to then be manipulated later on.

Any refinements of the regex code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the space in your pattern?

Comment: Well that was simple. Staring me right in the face and I miss it. How do I remove the [' '] from the number 6 though or is that just the output?

Comment: You don't have to remove anything, `findall` returns a list of strings that's the reason why it is enclosed between square brackets and quotes. You only need to select the item you want from the list.

Comment: Such a blonde day. Thank you! My brain hates regular expression and shut down when working with it :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Space to your pattern

   ```
   print re.findall(r"protocol': (.*?),", strevent)
   ```
2. Trim your white space from the result

   ```
   result = re.findall(r"protocol': (.*?),", strevent)
   print [ r.strip() for r in result ]
   ```
3. Why not try to load data to object as json object? It might be a lot easier for this case. [python json library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)